# What would be an idiomatic and semantic way to make integration tests on this Elixir GenServer?

Tags: elixir, integration-testing, gen-server

I'm building several worker with GenServer and I would like to implement both unit and integration tests on each worker.

For the first worker I built, this is the implementation code

```
defmodule CotacoesETL.Workers.Pesagro.CotacoesFetcher do
  @moduledoc """
  Todos os dias esse Worker visita a página da `Pesagro` e
  busca novos boletins do Mercado Agrícola, a fim de atualizar
  nossa base de dados.
  """

  use GenServer

  alias Cotacoes.Handlers.CotacaoHandler
  alias CotacoesETL.Integrations.PesagroAPI
  alias CotacoesETL.Workers.Pesagro.CotacaoDownloader

  require Logger

  @one_day 864 * 100 * 100 * 10
  @half_minute 30 * 100 * 10

  def start_link(_) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, nil, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def trigger_fetching do
    GenServer.cast(__MODULE__, :fetch)
  end

  @impl true
  def init(_) do
    # Process.send_after(__MODULE__, :schedule_fetch, @half_minute)
    {:ok, nil}
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_cast(:fetch, _) do
    Logger.info("[#{__MODULE__}] ==> Buscando novas cotações em Pesagro")

    document = PesagroAPI.fetch_document!()
    links = PesagroAPI.fetch_all_links(document)
    today = Date.utc_today()

    cotacoes =
      links
      |> Enum.map(&insert_cotacao(&1, today))
      |> Enum.filter(fn
        {:ok, cot} -> cot
        {:error, _} -> nil
      end)

    if Enum.empty?(cotacoes) do
      Logger.info("[#{__MODULE__}] ==> Nenhuma nova cotação encontrada em Pesagro")
    end

    # Agenda a próxima execução do Fetcher
    schedule_next_fetch()

    {:noreply, nil}
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_info(:schedule_fetch, state) do
    GenServer.cast(__MODULE__, :fetch)
    {:noreply, state}
  end

  defp schedule_next_fetch do
    Process.send_after(self(), :schedule_fetch, @one_day)
  end

  defp insert_cotacao(link, today) do
    with {:ok, cotacao} <- CotacaoHandler.insert_cotacao_pesagro(link, today) do
      base_name = CotacaoHandler.get_cotacao_file_base_name(cotacao)
      Logger.info("[#{__MODULE__}] ==> Cotação Pesagro #{base_name} inserida")
      GenServer.cast(CotacaoDownloader, {:download, cotacao})
      {:ok, cotacao}
    end
  end
end
```

Then I built the second worker, here's the source code:

```
defmodule CotacoesETL.Workers.Pesagro.CotacaoDownloader do
  @moduledoc """
  Este worker é responsável por baixar cada boletim da Pesagro.
  Assim que novos boletins são encontrados pelo worker `BoletinsFetcher`,
  uma mensagem é disparada para este worker para baixá-lo.

  Caso o boletim seja um PDF, o worker `PDFConverter` será acionado,
  e caso seja um ZIP, o worker `ZIPExtractor` será acionado em seu
  lugar.
  """

  use GenServer

  alias Cotacoes.Models.Cotacao
  alias CotacoesETL.Events.ConvertPDFEvent
  alias CotacoesETL.Events.ExtractZIPEvent
  alias CotacoesETL.Events.IngestCotacaoEvent
  alias CotacoesETL.Events.PDFConvertedEvent
  alias CotacoesETL.Handlers.PesagroHandler
  alias CotacoesETL.Logic.PesagroLogic
  alias CotacoesETL.Workers.PDFConverter
  alias CotacoesETL.Workers.Pesagro.CotacaoIngester
  alias CotacoesETL.Workers.ZIPExtractor

  require Logger

  @storage_path "/tmp/peapescarte/cotacoes/pesagro/"

  def start_link(_) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, nil, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  @impl true
  def init(_) do
    unless File.exists?(@storage_path) do
      File.mkdir_p!(@storage_path)
    end

    {:ok, nil}
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_cast({:download, cotacao}, _) do
    unless cotacao.baixada? do
      Logger.info("[#{__MODULE__}] ==> Baixando cotação #{cotacao.link} da Pesagro")

      {cotacao, file_path} = PesagroHandler.download_cotacao_from_pesagro!(@storage_path, cotacao)

      cotacao
      |> maybe_send_extract_zip_message(file_path)
      |> maybe_send_convert_pdf_message(file_path)
    end

    {:noreply, nil}
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_info({:download, cotacao}, _) do
    GenServer.cast(__MODULE__, {:download, cotacao})
    {:noreply, nil}
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_info({:pdf_converted, %PDFConvertedEvent{} = event}, state) do
    event = IngestCotacaoEvent.new(%{file_path: event.file_path, cotacao: event.cotacao})
    Process.send(CotacaoIngester, {:ingest, event}, [])

    {:noreply, state}
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_info({:zip_extracted, entries_path}, state) do
    for entry <- entries_path do
      {:ok, cotacao} = PesagroLogic.fetch_cotacao_by_file_path(entry, @storage_path)

      event =
        ConvertPDFEvent.new(%{
          cotacao: cotacao,
          pdf_path: entry,
          destination_path: @storage_path,
          issuer: self(),
          format: :txt
        })

      Process.send(PDFConverter, {:convert, event}, [])
    end

    {:noreply, state}
  end

  defp maybe_send_extract_zip_message(%Cotacao{tipo: :zip} = cotacao, path) do
    storage = Path.join(@storage_path, cotacao.id)

    event =
      ExtractZIPEvent.new(%{
        zip_path: path,
        destination_path: storage,
        issuer: self()
      })

    Process.send(ZIPExtractor, {:extract, event}, [])

    cotacao
  end

  defp maybe_send_extract_zip_message(cotacao, _), do: cotacao

  defp maybe_send_convert_pdf_message(%Cotacao{tipo: :pdf} = cotacao, path) do
    event =
      ConvertPDFEvent.new(%{
        cotacao: cotacao,
        pdf_path: path,
        destination_path: @storage_path,
        issuer: self(),
        format: :txt
      })

    Process.send(PDFConverter, {:convert, event}, [])

    cotacao
  end

  defp maybe_send_convert_pdf_message(cotacao, _), do: cotacao
end
```

The focus for this question is the GenServer implementation and not its dependencies (which are mostly API integrations and database connections that are already mocked on test env).

If you would like to see the complete source code for this implementation, go ahead at https://github.com/peapescarte/pescarte-plataforma/tree/main/apps/cotacoes_etl/lib/cotacoes_etl/workers/pesagro

So I ask for advice on how I could write integration tests on this GenServer implementation!

Comment: Actually, no. I refactored the whole genserver and workflow, so its more semanticaly correct but I'm stills trying to write integration tests for it. I;ll update the post code

Comment: Ok, I'll try to have a look at the source code.

Comment: Thanks for the availability!